# Printing the row out for a max column value

Tags: r, dplyr

I've progressed a bit with R but have been "slacking" or fogetting about the more basic functions. The issue I'm having now is using the new function learned `"pivot_longer"` I've adjusted my dataset so that its more workable finding the fastest lap-time.

The question at hand is : Find out who has the fastest lap time. I've tried using `max()` or `which.max()` which only printed out the actual max time of the column I selected.

How can I get a print that looks as follows "Lap - Name - Fastest Lap time" ?

My code:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
    
Mugello<- Mugello %>% pivot_longer(cols = 3:22)
which.max(Mugello$value)
Mugello[max(Mugello$value)]
```

Image of my dataset

[image]

Comment: `Mugello$name[which.max(Mugello$value)]`

Comment: Do you need to group by any columns?

Comment: Thank you @RonakShah This worked!, between both $ symbols i had a yellow text format so i thought it was popping a error, but apearantly thats ok.  I shouldve just tested it without just saying it wouldnt. Thanks again!